# Javascript prototype constructor/init

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototyping

What is the correct way of prototyping a "constructor" like function into every function?

For example,

```
function add(number1,number2){
  alert(number1 + number2);
}

Object.prototype.constructor = function(){
  alert("Calling " + arguments.callee);
}

add(5,5);
```

Will output 2 alerts, the first one saying "Calling add()", the second one saying "10".

Comment: That function is not magically an `Object`, and a function call doesn't magically create an object. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to intercept all function calls?